# How can I convert an EZ-Letter document to HTML or RTF?

Tags: html, rtf, ez-letter

I have recently been tasked with converting several documents from [EZ-Letter](http://www.accessaba.com/EZLetter.html) format to HTML, or at least to RTF, from which I can convert. I do not have access to the EZ-Letter application and am having a tough time finding a solution online both due to the keywords and the likely small-sized community.  I'll be asking the company directly during their office hours later this week to see if a solution exists, but asking on SO never hurts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documents I intended to convert to HTML were simple enough that I coded the HTML by hand using document images processed through EZ-Letter as reference.